# Is phantom wallet provides hooks

Tags: react, phantom-wallet, webhook

Is phantom wallet provides hooks for platforms like react js, next js? If you then please provide some documentations.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are looking for [Solana Wallet Adapter](https://github.com/anza-xyz/wallet-adapter).
You can easily add wallet connect feature using the Solana wallet adapter and it includes all popular wallets like Phantom, Solflare, Backpack, Glow etc.

As to your specific question, yes, there are many hooks to interact and get data from wallet.

- [Documentation](https://anza-xyz.github.io/wallet-adapter/)
- [Installation Guide](https://github.com/anza-xyz/wallet-adapter/blob/master/APP.md)